# Could not locate module @app1/shared mapped as... No mapping for self contained modules

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I've added few changes to sub-project `example-app-v12-monorepo` to reflect my situation:

1. Created `public_api.ts` file as barrel for shared classes in `examples/example-app-v12-monorepo/projects/app1/src/app/shared/public_api.ts`.
2. Configured `tsconfig.json` file in `examples/example-app-v12-monorepo/tsconfig.json` so it contains my changes:

```
"paths": {
  "@app1/shared": ["projects/app1/src/app/shared/public_api"]
}
```

3. Added modules mapping in `examples/example-app-v12-monorepo/projects/app1/jest.config.js`:

```
moduleNameMapper: {
 '@app1/shared': 'projects/app1/src/app/shared'
}
```

4. Changed relative path from folder shared to absolute. For example:

`'../shared/highlight.directive'` -> `'@app1/shared'`

Result:
When I try to run tests with `yarn test` I get error:

```
Configuration error:
    
Could not locate module @app1/shared mapped as:
projects/app1/src/app/shared.
    
Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
     "/@app1\/shared/": "projects/app1/src/app/shared"
  },
  "resolver": /Users/psmul/Desktop/jest-preset-angular/examples/example-app-v12-monorepo/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/resolvers/ng-jest-resolver.js
}
```

Is there a way to configure/fix this list of path mappings?

##edit due to investigation progress

When I added `<rootDir>` to absolute path I got closest of wanted results:
`@app1/shared': '<rootDir>/projects/app1/src/app/shared/public_api`
Resulted in:
`jest-preset-angular/examples/example-app-v12-monorepo/projects/app1/projects/app1/src/app/shared/public_api`

Basically, if I remove `/projects/app1` part it all works as intended.

My problem now:
In my (big) app I have a lot of pre-defined paths from the project root, while Jest needs to be set up on sub-project level (monorepo) I need to figure out a way to transform passed paths so it doesn't double path segments.
Example:
tsconfig path:
`example/path/project1/app/src/app/public_api.ts`
Jest setup level:
`project1/app/src/app/public_api.ts`

outcome:
`example/path/project1/app/project1/app/src/app/public_api.ts`

Is there a way to transform it?

Answer (score 0):

You must also have `public_api` in the mapper or you can change `public_api` in `index`

```js
module.exports = {
  rootDir: './',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@app1/shared': '<rootDir>/projects/app1/src/app/shared/public_api',
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer, however after applying your snippet suggestion I get the same error with different path:
`Could not locate module @app1/shared mapped as:/jest-preset-angular/examples/example-app-v12-monorepo/projects/app1/projects/app1/src/app/shared/public_api.`. Maybe rootDir is unnecessary here?

Comment: @psmul have you tried without root?

Comment: yes, outcome is almost the same (just path changed):
`Could not locate module @app1/shared mapped as: projects/app1/src/app/shared/public_api.`

Comment: @psmul can you reproduce on stackblitz?

Comment: Sorry, but this example is a bit too big to be transferred to stackblitz. However, in meantime, I was able to make a progress on my case. Would you mind reading the main thread? (##edit part)